# Changing html tag structure on window resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I would like to rebuild an html tag structure to a new one on resizing the browser window. Have anyone an idea how can I get from the first structure to the second structure. I need this for an responsive personal project. Maybe with an JavaScript resize Event, I don't know...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS Media Queries - does that for you.

Comment: Media Queries can change a DOM Structure?

Comment: If you have a proper DOM structure in the first place, then using media queries to do most things are sufficient. If you really need to change the dom there is always javascript, but it really isn't the best tool in most cases.

Comment: In this case it doesn't work with media queries.

Comment: No, but it can transform the content in such a way that it is displayed completely different.  See some examples at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21192082/1662973.  It is very popular with galleries or even where you are trying to display less content, i.e. full details vs. summary only.  I believe the splitting of your content should be will suited for that.  Also see http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/CSS3MediaQueries/Default.html

Comment: Like in your example. If you only define the css of the slide class in a certain breakpoint, then there is no need to hide it as it would just act as an invisible block element in the context you describe. It is a little hard to know how to give an answer, when you haven't given the CSS in use.

Comment: Do you have control over the generated slider content, then why not generate it correctly in the first place and then use media queries.  JavaScript for sizing is ugly.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the `resize` event on the window and then restructure your HTML when the window is below a certain size. Moving elements from the first structure to the second isn't a big problem, however the challenge lies in reverting that again. How will you know which of the `.item`'s belonged to which `.slide`?

One way to do this is to keep track of the parent for each `.item` in a separate `data-` attribute when you make the list:

```
function makeList() {
    var $slides = $('.slide'),
        $items = $();

    // For each slide set a data-attribute on all its child .item's 
    $slides.each(function(i) {
        var $item = $(this).children('.item');

        $item.attr('data-slide', i+1);
        $items = $items.add($item);
    });

    // Append all items directly to the wrapper
    $('.wrapper').html($items).attr('data-structure', 'list');
}
```

I set a data attribute to the `.wrapper` so we know that it's already converted to a list. Otherwise on every resize this would be fired, you only want it once (until it resizes back to where you want the slides).

When you want the slide again, loop through all the `.item`s and keep a list of slide number's. For each new `data-slide` number you encounter make a new slide and add that to the total list;

```
function makeSlides() {
    var $slides = $(),
        slideNumbers = [],
        $currentSlide = $();

    $('.item[data-slide]').each(function() {
        var $item = $(this),
            slideNumber = $item.attr('data-slide');

        // if the slide number wasn't in the array yet push the current slide into $slides and create a new one
        if(slideNumbers.indexOf(slideNumber) < 0) {
            $slides = $slides.add($currentSlide);
            $currentSlide = $('<div class="slide" />');

            slideNumbers.push(slideNumber);
        }
        $currentSlide.append($item);
    });

    // add the last currentSlide
    $slides = $slides.add($currentSlide);

    // place all slides in the wrapper
    $('.wrapper').html($slides).attr('data-structure', 'slides');
}
```

Then finally you bind the resize event and fire these functions when needed:

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    var currentStructure = $('.wrapper').attr('data-structure');

    if(window.innerWidth < 600) {
        if( currentStructure !== 'list') {
            makeList();
        }
    } else {
        if( currentStructure !== 'slides') {
            makeSlides();
        }
    }
});
```

#### jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gktLnw31/3/

I do think this could be a bit more efficient, but this is just a proof of concept. Hopefully it'll give you some insights.

Answer (score -1):

I would better take a look at [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) since it already includes the responsive design by default instead of trying to change it dynamically by code

Comment: It is a special problem. I would like to solve the problem be rewriting the DOM on resizing. I need this for jquery slider..

Comment: then maybe you could use jquery.resize() have a look at https://api.jquery.com/resize/